# Can I use Ag in combination with YouCompleteMe for tag autocompletion?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, the-silver-searcher

I have setup vim to use [Ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) for grepping and for use in the CtrlP plugin.

For tag autocompletion, I am using [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe). To get autocompletion suggestions for functions throughout the whole project, I have to use ctags which generates tagfiles. I prefer to not use any files but just use Ag to dynamically look for autocompletion suggestions. I am aware of the fact that this could be possibly too slow, but I'd like to try anyway. Is there a way to configure YouCompleteMe to use Ag for autocompletion?

Comment: I also opened an issue on the YouCompleteMe project: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1997

Comment: If needed, my Vim config is here: https://github.com/rbnvrw/.dotfiles

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was handled at the project's issue tracker.